# How do I pronounce the words יוׁ״ד קֵ״י בְּוָא״ו קֵ״י after "For the sake of the unification of the Holy One...?"

Tags: hebrew

Title. I'm not sure how to find out about it so I'll ask in here.

Shalom!

Comment: This may not apply to you, but generally, people who don't know how to say it also don't know what it really means, rendering any attempt at saying it pointless

Comment: Anything for Hashem I offer it up to Him until I am more educated on Hebrew. But according to another website I was also reading, its pronounced just the way its written "Yod, Kei, B'vav, Kei." Also I just learned reading this prayer is the custom of Sephardim.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya andy. Where have you seen these words?

Comment: It's in the Lishem Yichud prayer. There is a translation for these words in my Sephardic siddur. I hadn't learned what the apostrophes were for yet.

Comment: To indicate that it's a name of a letter, not a proper word

Comment: @andyhanukaai It's not an incantation but a declaration of intention. If you don't understand it, you can't intend it. You're much better off saying in English "May the following action take effect in accordance with the details described in this text which I don't understand".

Answer (score 1):

It's pronounced "Yud Kay b'Vov Kay." See footnote [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=16091#p=74).

Answer (score 0):

Siddur Hameforash by Rabbi Yaakov Wingarten brings the following:

See חיי אדם כלל ה’ סעיף כ"ז, where he states that it is prohibited or "איסור חמור” in his words, to pronoune the Hay.

The חתם סופר in שו"ת חו"מ בהשמטות סי’ קצ"ב also states that the minhag is not to pronounce the Hay.